# torch_tensorrt compilation error ,Unknown type bool encountered in graph lowering. This type is not supported in ONNX export

Tags: pytorch, onnx, tensorrt

I am following this article
https://pytorch.org/TensorRT/tutorials/serving_torch_tensorrt_with_triton.html , to serve the torch-tensorrt model in triton server.

but

```
import torch
import torch_tensorrt
torch.hub._validate_not_a_forked_repo=lambda a,b,c: True
from src.models.resnet2 import ResNet2
# load model
model = ResNet2(output_size = 2)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('Epoch_9_Valacc_0.911_9_.pth'))

**# Compile with Torch TensorRT
trt_model = torch_tensorrt.compile(model,
    inputs= [torch_tensorrt.Input((1, 3, 640, 640))],
    enabled_precisions= { torch.half}, # Run with FP32
     debug =True
)**
```

I am getting error at the last step , where its compiling a torch model
"Unknown type bool encountered in graph lowering. This type is not supported in ONNX export"

Please let me know how to overcome this

Answer (score 2):

The issue I encountered stemmed from directly compiling a PyTorch model using Torch-TensorRT, but Torch-TensorRT requires a TorchScript module.

Here's the solution:

```py
# Switch the model to evaluation mode
model.eval()

# Prepare an example input that you would normally provide to your model's forward() method.
sample_input = torch.randn((1, 3, 640, 640)).float()

# Use torch.jit.trace to generate a torch.jit.ScriptModule via tracing.
# This process will capture the model's computation graph.
traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(model, sample_input)
```

After tracing the model, use the traced_script_module for compilation with Torch-TensorRT. In this case, I used the tracing method to convert the PyTorch model to a TorchScript module.

```py
# Compile the traced_script_module with Torch-TensorRT
trt_model = torch._C._jit_to_backend("tensorrt", traced_script_module, spec)
```